# Different subnet range of ips are not working - windows server 2012 - virtual machine

Tags: networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines, windows-server-2012, windows

ip , subnet , default gateway

The main server is windows server 2012 and main ip is :

```
198.245.73.82 , 255.255.255.248 , 198.245.73.81
```

Now i have originally allocated ip range from my server provider as 198.245.73.82-86 (82,83,84,85,86)

On my hyper v virtual machine i am able to use all these 5 ips perfectly fine (83,84,85,86)

Now i requested new range of ip addresses and they gave me. But they are all failing. The support is claiming that problem resides at my side.

**My question is do you have any idea what might be problem that is caused by me ?**

The new ip range they gave me is like this

ip , subnet , default gateway

```
23.250.14.162 , 255.255.255.240 , 23.250.14.159
```

range : 23.250.14.162-74 (62,63....74)

Thank you for the answers.

Here the all network and hyper v configuration

host config 1: http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/a/1/host_1_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxynn.png
host config 2: http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/b/9/host_2_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxyng.png
host config 3: http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/d/3/host_3_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxynd.png
host config 4: http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/8/6/host_4_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxyn8.png
host config 5: http://fc04.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/2/b/host_6_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxymz.png
host config 6: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/c/2/host_5_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxyn6.png
host config 7: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/8/e/host_7_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxymn.png
host config 8: http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/5/8/host_8_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxymg.png
host config 9: http://fc00.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/b/c/host_9_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxym9.png
hyper v config 1: http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/c/4/virtual_1_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxylx.png
hyper v config 2: http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/0/d/virtual_2_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxylo.png
hyper v config 3: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/d/e/virtual_3_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxylc.png
hyper v config 4: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/9/4/virtual_4_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxyl6.png
hyper v config 5: http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/363/b/e/virtual_5_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxyku.png

Here on virtual hyper v operation system at the beginning given ips are working but the news are not screenshots

First one given at the same subnet of primary ip

http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/364/f/9/first_ones_works_by_monstermmorpg-d6zzz7u.png

And here one of the ip from new range different subnet not working

http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/364/7/a/no_connection_by_monstermmorpg-d6zzz80.png

All images can be downloaded from this link as a zip file

http://www.monstermmorpg.com/networkconfig.zip

Comment: What happened to your last question that was just like this? You're only showing one interface on the old subnet, how is the new subnet presented to this physical host, is it a different VLAN over the same physical connection? Do you have a new physical connection on the new subnet that you haven't enabled yet?

Comment: @MDMarra they just said use these ips. nothing else. so i entered what values they gave me and it is not working. i didn't add any other physical network or any other virtual network. etc. Only just changed network properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That network isn't magically available because some provider delegates those IPS to you. You need to configure an additional interface on your Hyper-V host to be on that subnet, create a vSwitch with that interface as the uplink, and put VMs on that vSwitch. You can't do all of this with a single physical interface unless you're using VLAN tagging at the vSwitch or guest, but none of your screenshots show this.

If you have no idea what any of this means, you should contact your service provider for help, or consider hiring a sysadmin with Hyper-V experience on an as-needed basis.

Comment: can you please explain more which interface ? my dedicated server only has 1 physical network interface. Also there is no configuration of interfaces at hyper v host. there is no ip binding or sub network binding etc. There are 3 options as can be seen here : http://fc02.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2013/363/c/4/virtual_1_by_monstermmorpg-d6zxylx.png

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not really a simpler way to explain this. You may want to purchase a book on Hyper-V and do some learning.

Comment: Lol you are talking such as there are 10000 parameters configuration to make. But in 14 simple screenshots i showed all of the network configuration parameters. There aren't any other related network configuration option. I checked everywhere. I believe you have no idea how to solve this problem.

Comment: lol problem was so simple. someone else just replied me at other place. the default gateway should be 161 not 159

Comment: While it is convention that the IP used for the gateway be the lowest in the subnet, it isn't a requirement, and you didn't even mention the subnet assigned.  Your provider will generally tell you the gateway address; it is theirs to give you the right one and yours to type it in correctly.  I guess @MDMarra was wrong to give you the benefit of the doubt in that.

Comment: @FalconMomot yes server provider gave me incorrect subnet. But someone else from webhostingtalk just figured it out it should be 161 from just looking the ip ranges. he is truly expert :D

Comment: As I said, it's convention.  It is an assumption, though, that your "IP range" really means 23.250.14.160/28 and another assumption that the lowest assignable address (.161) is the gateway.  These aren't assumptions we are apt to make, as professional administrators dealing with complex networks in which they don't always hold.  Your attitude is unfortunate.